# NativeBase Button getting squished inside flex

Tags: ios, react-native, button, native-base, react-flexbox-grid

Anyone knows how to solve this: in iOS, a button gets "squished" inside a Flex that has fixed height, but not on Android or web.

[Demo Link](https:////snack.expo.io/@joaomarceloods/nativebase-button-squished-inside-flex-in-ios)

Answer (score 0):

You've kept the container's height less than Button's and I think overflow is hidden in RN for iOS by default. Also, setting it overflow "visible" doesn't work. The same issue will happen with RN's Text and View.
https://snack.expo.io/@nishanbende/nativebase-button-squished-inside-flex-in-ios